# Extracting words with - included upper lowercase not working for words it only extracts chars

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to extract several words from a string with regex matcher &pattern. I did spend some time to make the regular expression I'm using but this doesn't work as expected, any help would be very appreciated.

I  made the regular expression I'm using but this doesn't work as expected, some help would be great. I'm able to extract the chars from the words I want but not the entire word.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Main {

public static void main (String[] args){

    String mebo = "1323 99BIMCP 1 2 BMWQ-CSPS-D1, 0192, '29229'";


    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[((a-zA-Z1-9-0)/W)]");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mebo);


    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.printf("Word is %s %n",matcher.group(0));

    }

}
}
```

> This is current output:
>
> Word is 1  Word is 3  Word is 2  Word is 3  Word is 9  Word is 9  Word
>   is B  Word is I  Word is M  Word is C  Word is P  Word is 1  Word is 2
>   Word is B  Word is M  Word is W  Word is Q  Word is -  Word is C  Word
>   is S  Word is P  Word is S  Word is -  Word is D  Word is 1  Word is 0
>   Word is 1  Word is 9  Word is 2  Word is 2  Word is 9  Word is 2  Word
>   is 2  Word is 9

============

My expectation is to iterate entire words for example:

String mebo = "1323 99BIMCP 1 2 BMWQ-CSPS-D1, 0192, '29229'"

> word is 1323 word is 99BIMCP word is 1 word is 2 word is BMWQ-CSPS-D1
>   word is 0192 word is 29229

Comment: I haven't read your question properly as Aleksei has made a suggestion above but for future reference I think `/W` should be `\W` or possibly even `\\W` because you have to escape the escape character

Comment: Use this `[\w-]+` https://regex101.com/r/rPDZwg/2/

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I think you need to add double escapes to your pattern

Comment: @CodeManiac Your suggested pattern has a problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen would love to know. i made small change.

Comment: @Matt indeed, I have it removed since the time to edit already passed.

Comment: Thanks everyone, @Code Maniac suggestion worked flawlessly, that tool you are using is great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this as it seems from your regex you want to include `character` `digit` and `-` in your match.

```
`[\w-]+`
```

- `[\w-]+` - Matches (a-z 0-9 _ and - ) one or more time.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPDZwg/2/)

Comment: One possible edge case: The term `"Hello World", ...` appears in the input.  Your regex would not be able to distinguish from escaped and unescaped whitespace  (my answer has issues too by the way)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i think you too missed this in your solution as you're splitting with space or comma. anyways thanks for pointing out. will update to make it more generic

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution here seems to be to ditch regex overall and just split the string instead. You want to allow digits, alphabetic characters and `-` in your words. Consider the following code:

```
for (String word : mebo.split("[^\\d\\w-]+")) {
    System.out.printf("Word is %s %n", word);
}
```

This should exhibit the desired behaviour. Note that this will generate some empty strings, unless you have the `+` in the splitting pattern.

What this does is splitting the input string between everything that does **not** match your desired characters. This is accomplished through using an inverted character class.

Comment: Just FYI, the pattern you are using in your split function is regex :)

Comment: shhh :) Don't spoil it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a regex split, followed by a regex replacement:

```
String mebo = "1323 99BIMCP 1 2 BMWQ-CSPS-D1, 0192, '29229'";
String[] parts = mebo.split("\\s*,?\\s+");
for (String part : parts) {
   System.out.println(part.replaceAll("[']", ""));
}

1323
99BIMCP
1
2
BMWQ-CSPS-D1
0192
29229
```

The logic here is to split on whitespace, possibly including a comma separator.  Then, we can do a regex replacement cleanup to remove stray characters such as single quotes.  Double quotes and any other unwanted characters can easily be added to the character class used for replacement.

In general, regex alone may not suffice here, and you may need a parser to cover every edge case.  Case in point, consider the following input line:

```
One, "Two or more", Three
```

My answer fails here, because it blindly splits on whitespace, and does not know that escaped whitespace is not a token.  A regex would also fail here.